# css circle div, border warps around 3/4ths of circle's circumference

Tags: css, html

I have a div that is a circle. I want to add a border around it that only wraps 3/4th of its circumference. Example :

[image]

my code so far:

```
<div id="Circle"></div>
#Circle  {
 overflow:hidden;
display:block;
float:left;
width:auto;
height:auto;
position: relative;
border-radius:50%;
-moz-border-radius:50%;
-webkit-border-radius:50%;
-khtml-border-radius: 50%;
background:#eee;
border: 3px solid #01542c;
z-index: 9;
padding:50%;
```

}

https://jsfiddle.net/pm97beyx/1/

My current solution involved making a div on top of it then positioning it as a mask to hide the border underneath, very crude I would say.

Comment: why don't you do it in SVG ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make the `border-top` transparent:

```
#Circle  {
     overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    position: relative;
    border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
    background:#eee;
    border: 10px solid #01542c;
    border-top:10px solid transparent;
    z-index: 9;
    padding:50%;
}
```

Result:
[image]

### [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w5zgcc17/)

Comment: would there be a way to make it border left-top? so its at an angle. In stead of just top bottom left or right.

Comment: @nick use CSS transform, and rotate the circle

Comment: Yes thats what im thinking but it then rotates the content within. I am trying to apply it to the border i add using :before, then hopefully it want effect inner content.

Comment: @nick well, you could just put the content in a div inside of it, and counter rotate it in the opposite direction :P I am not sure if that is the best way, but it works.

Comment: or else wrap the circle in a div with `position:relative;` then place the content in another div over it